# Method POST not supported Netflix Eureka and ZUUL

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-zuul, netflix-eureka

I am creating a Rest controller in JAVA . When I run the application locally , I am able to do POST operations. Then I create a JAR and then deploy it on a server . Plz note that I am using Netflix Eureka for service discovery and zuul as API gateway . The application starts running fine on server and it is registered in Eureka server as well . But when I use POST service , its giving me error : 405 Method  Post not supported .

Controller class

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.bp.budgetpulse.domain.FeedBackEmployeeDetails;
import com.bp.budgetpulse.service.FeedBackService;


@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1")
public class FeedBackController {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FeedBackService.class);

    @Autowired
    private FeedBackService feedbackService;

    /**
     * This method to save the feedback details
     * 
     * @param feedbackDetails
     * @param userName
     * @return response
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveEmployeeFeedbackDetails", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveEmployeeFeedbackDetails(@RequestBody FeedBackEmployeeDetails empFeedbackDetails) {
        return feedbackService.saveEmployeeFeedbackDetails(empFeedbackDetails);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * this method to get the feedback details
     * 
     * @return feedback details
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getFeedBackDetails/{email}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public FeedBackEmployeeDetails getFeedBackDetails(@PathVariable String email) {
        return feedbackService.getFeedBackDetails(email);
    }
}
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve it.?

Answer (score -1):

POST method is supported in Netflix Eureka and ZUUL. Netflix Eureka and ZUUL do not impose any restriction on the API Methods. Here is a sample controller code that I have written that works without any issues in a Netflix Eureka and ZUUL environment:

```
import com.aj.gradingservice.model.Grade;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class GradeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GradeController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "ping", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> ping() {
        Map<String, String> response = new HashMap<>();
        response.put("message", "pong");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "grades", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Grade>> getGrades() {
        logger.info("In GradeController.getGrades(), fetching list of grades");
        List<Grade> grades = new ArrayList<>();
        grades.add(new Grade(1, "P001", "A+"));
        grades.add(new Grade(2, "C001", "A"));
        grades.add(new Grade(3, "M001", "B+"));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(grades, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "grade", method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Grade> createGrade(@RequestBody Grade grade) {
        logger.info("Request received is: " + grade );
        Grade gradeCreated = new Grade(grade.getId(),grade.getStudentId(),grade.getGrade());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(gradeCreated, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

I have written a blog post with the detailed explanation of setting up a Netflix Eureka and Zuul environment and there is end to end working code in GitHub. Please check: http://softwaredevelopercentral.blogspot.com/2018/02/spring-cloud-eureka-and-zuul.html